# MarkLogic - How can you do a collection-delete using Java API?

Tags: marklogic

How can you do a collection-delete using [Java API](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/index.html)? I'm using a JSONDocumentManager for my CRUD operations. Is there a way to do something like:

```
xdmp:collection-delete("myCollection")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [QueryManager.delete()](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/QueryManager.html#delete(com.marklogic.client.query.DeleteQueryDefinition)) passing it a [QueryManager.newDeleteDefinition()](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/QueryManager.html#newDeleteDefinition()) and in the [DeleteQueryDefinition](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/DeleteQueryDefinition.html) set the list of collections which you want to have deleted.

Comment: How can I do the same with client-api-java 2.0.5?